# How to reduce delay of the pop up window in android?

Tags: android, canvas, popup, popupwindow

[This program output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojuMm.jpg)

You all see the above picture and run the below code.

```
public class NewClass extends View{

    float initialX,initialY;
    View view;
    Paint paint;
    TextView txtView;
    PopupWindow pop;
    public NewClass(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        paint=new Paint();
        view=new View(context);

        txtView = new TextView(getContext());
        pop = new PopupWindow(getContext());

        txtView.setTextSize(10);
        txtView.setText("sss");
        txtView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        txtView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);

        pop.setContentView(txtView);
        pop.setHeight(20);
        pop.setWidth(40);
        OnTouchChild();

    }

    public void OnTouchChild() {

        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = event.getX();
                        initialY = event.getY();

                        if (pop.isShowing()) {
                            pop.dismiss();
                        }
                String s=String.valueOf(initialX);
                txtView.setText(s);

                        pop.showAsDropDown(view,100,100,Gravity.CENTER);

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        initialX = event.getX();
                        initialY = event.getY();

                        if (pop.isShowing())
                            pop.dismiss();

                        String s1=String.valueOf(initialX);

                        txtView.setText(s1);

                        pop.showAsDropDown(view,100,100,Gravity.CENTER);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You use both action down and action move options of above coding.

my question is how to reduce the delay of showing Pop Up window?

please who all knows answer me.!